# How to retrieve image from a JSON Response from API using retrofit

Tags: android, json, image, retrofit, picasso

I'm getting a JSON response where it shows my image path but i can't just directly load the image from it's path using retrofit.

Here's the JSON Output sample:

```
{
"Emp_Photo": "/Images/2018_07_02_05_30_24.jpg",
}
```

I tried fetching and storing the value of Emp_Photo into a string and loaded the string into imageview using picasso but it doesn't work.

Here's some part of my code which i'm trying to accomplish:

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching Data...");
        progressDialog.show();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiClient.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Fetchemployeedetailsinterface service = retrofit.create(Fetchemployeedetailsinterface.class);

//Result is our pojo class
        SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0);
       String emailtoken= settings.getString("email", "").toString();
        Call<ResponseData> call = service.Bind_Employee_Details_Based_On_Id(emailtoken);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseData> call, Response<ResponseData> response) {
                //.getMessage is POJO method to listen for final json output
                List<MessageItem> listResponse =response.body().getMessage();
                String fname=listResponse.get(0).getEmpFirstName();
                String lname=listResponse.get(0).getEmpLastName();
                String email=listResponse.get(0).getEmpEmail();
                String address=listResponse.get(0).getEmpAddress();
                String joindt=listResponse.get(0).getJoiningDate();
                String imgaddress=listResponse.get(0).getEmpPhoto();

                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imgaddress).into(pick);
                ettvname.setText(fname+"-"+lname);
                etfname.setText(fname);
                etlname.setText(lname);
               etemail.setText(email);
               etaddress.setText(address);
               etjoindt.setText(joindt);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseData> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Emp_Photo` is just the path of the image. You should convert it to a full URL, then load it with Picasso.

```
String imageUrl = YOUR_ROOT_IMAGE + imgaddress
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imageUrl).into(pick);
```

---

Other advice:

And you should apply some conventions to make your code easier to read.

```
service.Bind_Employee_Details_Based_On_Id() -> service.bindEmployeeDetailsBasedOnId()
Fetchemployeedetailsinterface -> FetchEmployeeDetailsInterface
...
```

And here:

```
List<MessageItem> listResponse =response.body().getMessage();
String fname=listResponse.get(0).getEmpFirstName();
```

You should check and make sure listResponse has at least 1 item to prevent your app crash at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in your description you are getting the only path of the image. But, you are not getting the full path of your image. So, you should have to required fill path of your image from where you can fetch image and load in your image view easily. For that you have to follow below method:

```
String image = base_URL + imgaddress;  //Here base URL means initial path of your image or server.
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imgaddress).into(pick);
```

Try to get base_URL in response or another way.